# How can I modify the Bulma CSS framework to get the desired color theme and alignments?

Tags: html, css, sass, bulma

I'm about to build a website and do a case study on it. I don't necessarily want to dive deep into CSS to get my desired design, foremost due to time pressure. So I thought I would use a framework to get the design done asap. I picked Bulma because I was aiming for a minimalistic and modern design. However, I'm not satisfied with the theme colours which Bulma has.

I'm wondering how can I modify CSS to get the desired colours and alignments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bulma Start](https://bulma.io/bulma-start/) is an easy way to customize your project. Set up Bulma and run the watchers (css & js) so code changes will be reflected in your browser:

```
cd my-bulma-project
npm install
npm start
```

In `_sass/main.scss`, follow the commented instructions for adding a new color. Here's an example:

```
// 2. Set your own initial variables
$orange: #ffb14a;
$blue: #99abe0;

// 3. Set the derived variables
// Use the new orange as the primary color
$primary: $orange;
$secondary: $blue;

// 4. Import the rest of Bulma
@import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma";

.new-class {
  background-color: $primary;
  border-top: 2px solid $secondary;
}
```

For more extensive customization and theming, I recommend exploring the [Customize](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/) docs on the Bulma site for creating a custom implementation using scss.

Here's an example from the Bulma website for quick customization with scss.

```
// Import a Google Font
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700');

// Set your brand colors
$purple: #8A4D76;
$pink: #FA7C91;
$brown: #757763;
$beige-light: #D0D1CD;
$beige-lighter: #EFF0EB;

// Update Bulma's global variables
$family-sans-serif: "Nunito", sans-serif;
$grey-dark: $brown;
$grey-light: $beige-light;
$primary: $purple;
$link: $pink;

// Update some of Bulma's component variables
$control-border-width: 2px;
$input-background-color: $beige-lighter;
$input-border-color: transparent;
$input-shadow: none;

// Import the rest of Bulma
@import "../path/to/bulma";
```

Comment: Thank you very much @carbonspace for your help. It did finally work.
My issue is now how to make the website still look like I want everywhere. Because I uploaded to GitHub and the changes weren't applied any more.
Do you have any tips for me to solve that? I'm a student and still an absolute beginner on frontend programming.

Comment: @Ayoub Check the console for errors and make sure you have uploaded all required dependencies and assets to your GitHub. When you post questions to StackOverflow, it really helps to provide sample code that you've tried that shows you're attempting to find the answer. Help us help you. Good luck.